# if setState cant be used than what does

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to set a state of the user by getting a value from my database and then using it. For some reason the state does not update itself I have tried await and async. What other options exists if this one can't be reliable to make this be a value.

I do get the following error :  `Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
- node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:33:20 in printWarning
- node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:57:25 in warning
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12196:6 in warnAboutUpdateOnUnmounted
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13273:41 in scheduleWorkImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:6224:19 in enqueueSetState
- node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:242:31 in setState
* null:null in componentWillMount$
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:296:30 in invoke
- ... 13 more stack frames from framework internals`

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    userPhoneNumber: "",
  };
}
async componentWillMount() {
  await firebase.database().ref('/Users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).on('value', async snap => {
    if (snap) {
      await this._setPhone(snap.val())
    } else {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Phone')
    }
  });


  console.log(this.state.userPhoneNumber);

}
_setPhone = (snap) => {
  const val = parseInt(snap, 10);
  this.setState({
    userPhoneNumber: val
  })
};
```

Comment: That's weird. It should work. You don't need `await` here though: `await this._setPhone(snap.val())`

Comment: please put valid JS class syntax, and why do you call `this._setPhone()` with `await`?

Comment: added the await as another attempt to make this work both don't work

Comment: You're setting state somewhere AFTER navigating away, ensure that you don't. You have probably omitted key parts of this component so hard to say where.

Comment: you do not need any `async` and `await` in this code, because as I see you are using a callback approach, and you should use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount`, and again, please provide valid class syntax to be sure your problems are not related to anything else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that you are receiving the correct value for `snap`. Then the issue that you have is that `setState` is asynchronous. That means it takes time for state to set.

Unfortunately they way you are checking your state to see if the value has been set is wrong.

You should use a callback in the `setState` function, so your `setState` would become:

`this.setState({userPhoneNumber: val}. () => console.log(this.state.userPhoneNumber));`

I would recommend taking a read of the following articles by Michael Chan that go into more detail about setting state

https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-is-asynchronous-52ead919a3f0
https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296
https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-function-56eb940f84b6

There are also a few issues with your use of `async/await` and `promises` it looks like you are mixing the syntax between them. You either use one or the other, not both. This [article](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8) goes into detail about the differences between them.

`this.setState` does not return a promise so using `await this.setState` does nothing.

This is how I would refactor your code:

```
componentDidMount() { // componentWillMount is deprecated
  // you are using a promise to access firebase so you shouldn't be using `async/await`
  firebase.database().ref('/Users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).on('value', snap => {
    if (snap) {
      this._setPhone(snap.val()) // remove the await as it is not doing anything
    } else {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Phone')
    }
  });
}

_setPhone = (snap) => {
  const val = parseInt(snap, 10);
  this.setState({ userPhoneNumber: val}, () => console.log(this.state.userPhoneNumber)) // include the callback to check the value of state
};
```

## Updated question

You must be calling `setState` when the component has been unmounted. You need to check to make sure that your component is mounted before calling setState.

One way of doing it is by having a boolean flag that monitors when the component is mounted.

```
componentDidMount () {
  this._isMounted = true;
}

componentWillMount () {
  this._isMounted = false;
}
```

when you set your state you can do something like this

```
if (this._isMounted) {
  this.setState({key: value});
}
```

You can see more about it here https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

> Just set a _isMounted property to true in componentDidMount and set
>   it to false in componentWillUnmount, and use this variable to check
>   your component’s status

This it not an ideal solution but it is the simplest, as you really should be cancelling your promises etc, so that `setState` is never called as the promise has been cancelled.

Comment: thank for the answer that's why I added the await to make it will set using a callback will not allow me to continue using this value that is needed for the next few lines in component will mount

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Using the "isMounted" strategy is sub-optimal, a better approach would be to unsubscribe from the firebase event in `componentWillUnmount()`, this will allow the unmounted instance to be garbage collected and avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @Lennholm I did mention that it is not an ideal solution.